# Asynchronous processing of arrays (Promise.all or for..of)

Tags: javascript

I know there is a lot of information on this and I have read several articles, but I am still wandering.

I have an array of HTTP request urls. The order of each element in the array is very important. I want to get a response by fetching these request urls, and put the responses in the same order as the original array.

Below is the code I wrote. I thought it was right to use promise.all. We found promise.all to process arrays in parallel, but ordering is not guaranteed. (Is this correct?)

```js
const getAllImagePaths = async urls => {
  let copyPaths = [];

  try {
    const data = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)));

    for (let item of data) {
      const { url } = item;
      copyPaths.push(url);
    }

    return copyPaths;
  } catch (err) {
    const { response } = err;

    if (response) alert(MESSAGES.GET_PHOTOS_FAIL);
  }
};
```

So I modified the code by using the for..of statement.

```js
const getAllImagePaths = async urls => {
  let copyPaths = [];

  try {
    for(let url of urls) {
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const json = await res.json();
      const data = json.parse();

      const { url } = data;

      copyPaths.push(data);
    }

    return copyPaths;
  } catch (err) {
    const { response } = err;

    if (response) alert(MESSAGES.GET_PHOTOS_FAIL);
  }
};
```

However, when the for of statement is used, the response type of the data is 'cors'.

So to fix this, should I change the data to json and then parse the json again to use the data? I think this is very weird. This is because I only want to contain information called 'url' in the response object in the array.

Comment: "We found promise.all to process arrays in parallel, but ordering is not guaranteed. (Is this correct?)" — No. The order the promises resolve in isn't guaranteed, but what the Promise.all promise resolves it will do so with all the results in the same order that they went in in.

Comment: "*We found promise.all to process arrays in parallel, but ordering is not guaranteed. (Is this correct?)*" no, it is not

Comment: "However, when the for of statement is used, the response type of the data is 'cors'." — I don't have time to build a test case, but I'd expect that to error with the redeclaration of `url` in the same scope with `const`.

Comment: If the `data` you get from `Promise.all` weren't in order, using a `for-of` to loop over it and push each entry into a new array wouldn't be in order either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We found promise.all to process arrays in parallel, but ordering is not guaranteed. (Is this correct?)

No, it isn't correct. The result array you get on fulfillment of the `Promise.all` promise is in the **same order** as the input array, regardless of the order in which the input promises settled. Here's an example:

```js
function delayedValue(ms, value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Resolving with ${value}`);
            resolve(value);
        }, ms);
    });
}

async function example() {
    const results = await Promise.all([
        delayedValue(100, 1),
        delayedValue(10,  2),
        delayedValue(200, 3),
    ]);
    console.log(`results: ${results}`);
}

example();
```

So you can just use the result directly:

```
const getAllImagePaths = async urls => {
  try {
    const data = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)));
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    const { response } = err;

    if (response) alert(MESSAGES.GET_PHOTOS_FAIL);
  }
};
```

Comment: hi @T.J. Crowder +1. It means that the **individual promises** can be resolved in any order, (which doesn't matter because the purpose of all() is to get promises **in parallel**), what really matters is that **always** it returns an array with the results in the same order as **we put them in the array**, right? THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: @Coder23 - Right, the results array is in the order of the input array. *"...which doesn't matter because the purpose of all() is to get promises in parallel..."* There's a common misconception that you **might** be falling into (or might not!), so just in case: The promises settle in whatever order they settle in **regardless** of how you *observe* that (`Promise.all` or something else). `Promise.all` doesn't start or run the work being done, it just observes it being *finished*. Again, just in case. :-)

Comment: Great @T.J. Crowder, thank you +1. I've learned a lot of with your posts. Thanks for correcting my misunderstanding.